# RxJava Android: выполнить метод в другом потоке для каждого элемента списка

Tags: android, rxjava, rxandroid

Здравствуйте.

Только начал пробовать разбираться с `RxJava` и вот уже несколько часов бьюсь над тем, чтобы выполнить метод в отдельном потоке для каждого элемента списка. Суть такова: есть `ArrayList` неких объектов `Photo`. Для каждого из них нужно выполнить метод, работающий с сетью и увеличить значение внутри прогресс-бара у диалогового окна после каждого выполнения. Сейчас у меня это выглядит так:

```
Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(photoArrayList))
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .flatMapIterable(list -> list)
                        .filter(photo -> photo != null)
                        .map(photo -> некийМетод(photo))
                        .subscribe(result -> loadingDialog.incrementProgress(1), e -> onImagesUploadComplete(false), () -> onImagesUploadComplete(true));
```

Очевидно, что это сделано коряво и выдает `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Честно говоря, не понимаю, где еще, кроме как в методе `just()` можно выполнить метод не в UI потоке?
Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что после `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.maintThread())`, все будет выполняться в UI-потоке. Принцип прост:

```
someObservable
    //все вызовы здесь будут выполняться в THREAD_1
    .subscribeOn(THREAD_1)
    .observeOn(THREAD_2)
    //здесь все вызовы в THREAD_2
    .observeOn(THREAD_3)
    //здесь все вызовы в THREAD_3
    //и так далее
```

Под "все вызовы" я подразумеваю любые `map()`, `doOnNext/Error/Complete()`, `subscribe()` - короче, все.

Для того, чтобы у Вас все заработало достаточно перенести `subscribeOn()` и `observeOn()` таким образом:

```
Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(photoArrayList))
                        .flatMapIterable(list -> list)
                        .filter(photo -> photo != null)
                        .map(photo -> некийМетод(photo)) //так как этот вызов до subscribeOn(io), то map будет выполняться в io-потоке
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) //чтобы все верхние функторы работали в `io` потоке
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) //все нижние функторы будут выполняться в UI-потоке
                        .subscribe(result -> loadingDialog.incrementProgress(1), e -> onImagesUploadComplete(false), () -> onImagesUploadComplete(true));
```

Comment: Действительно, все так и оказалось. Спасибо огромное за помощь, а то я так бы и сидел в попытках решить проблему. Странно, что среди всех "гайдов для новичков" как в русском, так и англоязычном сегменте я не встретил упоминания про эту "фичу".

Comment: вроде бы тут это раскрыто https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jdvLrYZfB4